# Google Analytics: How to display the breakdown of an event parameter over custom period?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I've an app logging an event in Firebase analytics. This event has a parameter, and I can see the breakdown of this parameter's values over the last 30 minutes:

[image]

I'd like to see this breakdown over longer period e.g. over the last 7 days.

How can I see or export these data using Google Analytics or Firebase Analytics ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, go to your `Custom definitions` Firebase section and create custom dimensions. Set your scope to `Event` and select `modelName` as your Event parameter (Dimension name and Description can be set as you want). Than start logging from your Android app:

```
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("eventName") {
  param("modelName", "ESML")
}
```

After 24 hours or some time you should see in your event section a new graph describing data you demanded for longer period. You can use your new dimension also in some other event. Just send it as another event parameter and you will see.

Good inspiration for me was [this article](https://medium.com/lost-but-coding/setting-up-firebase-analytics-event-custom-parameters-dimensions-and-metrics-219cc3f3c356) and the two videos posted inside it. It helped me a lot, firebase docs didn't.

Answer (score -1):

You have to activate the parameter in the interface and from the next 24h you will start seeing it in the reports.

You cannot export history unless you have linked Analytics to BigQuery.

Comment: Thanks, but where do you activate the parameter in the Google Analytics interface ?

Comment: Custom parameters are added through "Manage Custom Definitions" menu on top of the event list

Comment: I've clarified my question: I already have my event and its parameter listed in Google Analytics. But when I click on the event, I see the percentage of each parameter's values over the last 30 minutes only cf picture. How can I see this breakdown over a longer timeframe ?

Comment: Use Analysis report or BiqQuery

Comment: Where is the Analysis report menu ?

Comment: You mean creating an Exploration analysis from the "Analysis Hub" menu ? Any tutorial to see the breakdown I'm looking for ?

Comment: Yes, I mean that report.

Comment: I've done that but I don't see how to display the percentage of each value of the parameter of my event

Comment: If the data is aggregated then you should use BigQuery as indicated above. There the data is raw.